# Differenet results from 2 identical gps modules using the same program at the same location

Tags: gps

I have two identical gps modules running the same program with antennas side by side. I get different results. I don't understand why

One example is `4211.41545` from the first unit and `4211.41481` from the second   the timestamp is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the values you quote are so I will assume that the value you are showing is the Lat or Long value from the NMEA output data.  If this is the case then the difference between the values is 0.00064 minutes of arc.  The maximum physical distance that this will represent is around 1.1 metres (along a great circle).  At 60 degrees north this would correspond to around 55cm in an E/W direction.

You do not say how far apart the antennae are or whether there are any obstructions above the level of their horizons which will introduce varying multipath signals that will be different for the two antennae.  The two receivers will not necessarily be sampling the satellite signals at the same instants and so can have marginally different signal timings resulting in a different position result.

A typical consumer grade GPS will have a CEP figure of 2.5 metres meaning that 50% of the values for position in an unobstructed sky view position will lie within a 2.5 metre radius circle of the true position.

Taking this into account you should not expect any two adjacent GPS devices to give identical results.